# Phonegap - How to open external link inside the app

Tags: html, cordova

I'm stuck. I'm working on a iOS phonegap app. On my homepage I have a link

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/file/news.html" rel="external" target="_system"><IMAGE></a>
```

And I have also added *mysite.com into the Cordova.plist (ExternalHosts).

But when I click on the link it will open up a browser and link me to that page. I have tried target="_self", but it doesn't work. How to make it open the page within the app itself?

Comment: See the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547852/phonegap-inappbrowser-not-working-need-to-open-the-url-inside-the-app?noredirect=1&lq=1#): it at least worked on Android for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can push it to browser using this javascript snip,

```
window.open("http://yourexternallink.com","_system");
```

Even if you have inAppBrowser installed, this will take you to browser..

If you wish to open the link inside your app, you need below snippet,

```
var onInApp = window.open('http://paymentpage.com', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done,toolbar=no');
```

make sure that you added `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` plugin..

Comment: i'm using cordova, and i don't thing the plugin run differently through these two engine, but it doesn't worked for me

Comment: setting hidden to no made it work, and it work better than the other answer, i edit it for you, you can accept or reject once you check

Comment: If you are sure about the answer please edit... This was posted months ago and number of versions released after that.. thanks

Comment: i'm sure, also another way is to say the browser to become visible later, but normally you wont see a thing by using above code. you need to edit, or approve my edit as i already done that

Comment: Please refer this link, you'll get more idea, https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html

Comment: I try all thinks but link is stillopening in browser, I just want to open with in app

Answer (score 0):

Use inApp Browser [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

The InAppBrowser is a web-browser that is shown in your app when you use the window.open call.

in ios add

`<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />` to config.xml 
 and just call window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
 etc.. more info [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

Comment: It still open up on a browser.