# Phone gap build - All links open in the default browser, not in application

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins

After the creation of my application, I add this in my config file:

```
...
<content src="http://www.mywebsite.com" />
...
```

I launch the android version of my application on [build.phonegap.com](https://build.phonegap.com). My application is normally installed with the launch page of my website, until now everything is good.

The problem is that if I click on a link, it does not open in the application but in a browser!

Comment: are you making a website link as a phonegap app?

Comment: I didn't change nothing,

Comment: then you cant open inside an app.check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737582/phonegap-how-to-open-external-link-inside-the-app?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

If you want *"www.mywebsite.com"* to open within your phonegap application you will need to direct the link to point to an iframe. You can make the iframe as follows.

```
<iframe src="http://www.mywebsite.com"></iframe>
```

An example of a full screen iframe is below.

```
<iframe src="http://www.mywebsite.com" style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%">
```

You could direct your user to a page within your application that contains a full screen iframe and they will view your website as if they never left your app.

Comment: i can have home page on my application, without iframe, but all link in this not to be able to open in same app, but in default browser.
<iframe> doesn't work for me !