# How to open link in external browser instead of in-app?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

I've been trying to figure out how to open an URL that you open within the Instagram app, in an external browser (Safari, Chrome) rather than the in-build Instagram-browser.

Here's [an example page](https://www.instagram.com/giftchest.4.free) that does exactly what I want. It asks you to leave Instagram app and opens external browser visiting his website.

I tried a lot of things, like using `window.open` with `_blank`, `_system`, etc. Also tried these within a `<a href="...`. None of these solutions worked.

Answer (score -2):

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737582/phonegap-how-to-open-external-link-inside-the-app) with the same problem.

You can push it to browser using this javascript snip:

```
window.open("http://yourexternallink.com","_system");
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this and I tried it again for you, but it doesn't work. All it does is redirecting to the in-build Instagram browser again. No popup asking to open the link in the browser. Any other idea?The example page I posed does exactly what I want if you open that page on your instagram mobile app.

Comment: I kind of find out he's using some kind of url shortener which is then redirecting to his site. The url shortener does the trick, but I don't know what it exactly does.