# PhoneGap - inappbrowser not working - Need to open the URL inside the app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

There are so many questions related to this like, [Phonegap - How to open external link inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737582/phonegap-how-to-open-external-link-inside-the-app) .

I want to open the website URL inside the app (not asking which browser need to open) when open the app.

But it asked which browser you need to open.... What I have done mistake here? **(This is working fine on emulator, but when I install it to android phone it asked which browser......)**

My config file

```
<access origin="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.2" />
```

Index File

```
<script>
    window.open('http://example.com', '_self', 'location=no,hidden=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done,toolbar=no'); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to configure the whitelist plugin to allow the internal navigation of external sites, you can do it with `allow-navigation` tag like this:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: Thanks, But what is the difference between `<access origin="*" />` and `<allow-navigation href="*" />`?

Comment: `access` is for network requests (images, external css and js, XHRs, etc), `allow-navigation` is for the Cordova webview navigation (websites where it's allowed to navigate to)

Comment: This worked for me after seeing a lot of solutions :)